# Cannot convert from 'const wchar_t *' to '_TCHAR *'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, porting, visual-c++-6

```
_TCHAR* strGroupName = NULL;
const _TCHAR* strTempName = NULL;

//Assign some value to strTempName

strGroupName = _tcschr(strTempName, 92) //C2440
```

I get an error at the above line while compiling this code in VS2008. In VC6 it compiles fine.

> Error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from
>   'const wchar_t *' to '_TCHAR *'

What seems to be the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try casting it as

```
strGroupName = (_TCHAR*)_tcschr(strTempName, 92);
```

Seems to me that VS2008 got a little more strict on type casts, and won't automatically do them in some cases.

Answer (score 8):

```
strGroupName = const_cast<_TCHAR*>( _tcschr(strTempName, 92));
```

This is because the variant of the function you're using has a const _TCHAR* as input and returns a const _TCHAR*.

Another variant would be to have strTempName declared as _TCHAR*, and not as const _TCHAR*. In this case, the variant function having a _TCHAR* parameter and returning a _TCHAR* value is used.

Comment: Is Jack's answer fine? It got rid of the compilation error but I want to know the difference between his and yours.

Comment: This version is better: it allows you to be specific about what the cast is for, i.e. it's not casting from some unrelated type, it's just removing the const.

Comment: @Bobby Using const_cast operation will allow you to easy find the const casting in the code by performing a simple search. I don't recomment const casting unless is really necessary.

The second alternative (make strTempName as non-const) is my preferred, because it implies no further constness changing. Btw, is any reason why you declared strTempName as const?

Answer (score 2):

`_tcschr` is returning a const pointer. Hence the return value should be `const _TCHAR* strGroupName = NULL;` If it is not possible to change strGroupName to a const pointer then declare both the pointers as non-const pointers.

Comment: This is fine but I cannot change strGroupName to const because it will affect the rest of the code which does not expect a const variable. Functions for example.

Comment: Then make strTempName & strGroupName  both non-const.

Comment: +1 including the comment that both can be non-const (perhaps add it to the answer?)

Answer (score 2):

`strGroupName` should also be a pointer to `const`.

```
const _TCHAR* strGroupName = _tcschr(strTempName, 92);
```

No need to declare it until the call to initialise it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when moving from C++14->20, was able to fix it by setting /Zc:StrictStrings- under CommandLine in my build properties.