# Concat a wchar_t and TCHAR

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi i need in my project to concat the name of my dialogbox (type wchar_t) and the name of a configuration (type TCHAR).
How can i do this?
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends, a TCHAR is ether a `char` or `wchar_t` depending on whether you build your appication as Unicode or not. If you build your app as Unicode you can simply do:

```
wcscat_s(dest, extra);
```

If you do not build your app as Unicode, you need to either convert the string of TCHAR:s (which is then a string of `char`:s) into a string of `wchar_t`:s or your string of `wchar_t`:s into a string of `char`:s. To do that you should look into the [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) functions. Both of these can look a little bit scary taking a lot of parameters so I usually use some helpers (please note that proper error-handling has been removed for clarity, a proper solution would also call the functions mentioned above in a loop that resizes the buffer if the call fails with `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`):

```
std::wstring multiByteToWideChar(const std::string &s)
{
  std::vector<wchar_t> buf(s.length() * 2);
  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,
                      MB_PRECOMPOSED,
                      s.c_str(),
                      s.length(),
                      &buf[0],
                      buf.size());
  return std::wstring(&buf[0]);
}

std::string wideCharToMultiByte(const std::wstring &s)
{
  std::vector<char> buf(s.length() * 2);
  BOOL usedDefault = FALSE;
  WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,
                      WC_COMPOSITECHECK | WC_DEFAULTCHAR,
                      s.c_str(),
                      s.length(),
                      &buf[0],
                      buf.size(),
                      "?",
                      &usedDefault);
  return std::string(&buf[0]);
}
```

In addition to those I set up a type-traits class so I can compile my projects as Unicode or not without caring:

```
template <class CharT>
struct string_converter_t;

template <>
struct string_converter_t<char>
{
  static std::wstring toUnicode(const std::string &s)
  {
    return multiByteToWideChar(s);
  }
  static std::string toAscii(const std::string &s)
  {
    return s;
  }
  static std::string fromUnicode(const std::wstring &s)
  {
    return wideCharToMultiByte(s);
  }
  static std::string fromAscii(const std::string &s)
  {
    return s;
  }
};
```

And an almost identical instance for the `wchar_t` (which I leave as an excerise). In your case you could then simply do:

```
std::wstring result = dialog_name + string_converter_t<TCHAR>::toUnicode(config_name);
```

Comment: Of course, any application built in the last decade should probably be built as Unicode, so this is a pretty simple task. :-)

Comment: thanks, i used wcscat_s(dest, extra); it works TCHAR is a wchar and i build my project in unicode :)

Comment: @CodyGray: Yup, but just making your code UTF-16 is not enough if you want to make sure it always work. A code point in UTF-16 can actually span more than one `wchar_t` which is something few people account for (me included).

Answer (score 2):

You mean TCHAR*? Because it would be kinda weird to have a single character as a name. Anyways: Just cast the TCHAR's to wchar_t - TCHAR is either char or wchar_t, either way it's save to cast to wchar_t.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842072.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to this: [Cannot convert from 'const wchar_t *' to '_TCHAR *'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999727/cannot-convert-from-const-wchar-t-to-tchar)

To manipulate different type of chars manually have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/TipsnTricks/StringManipulations.aspx